# How to draw a line between 2 points on a sphere?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

I have globe and I need to draw a line from 1 point on it to another.

I already have code that takes in latitude/longitude and maps it to X,Y,Z coordinate. 
I am using `SCNSphere` to represent the globe and `SCNShape` with `path` being set to an arc created with `UIBezierPath`.

Here comes the problem, I don't know how to rotate the `SCNShape` to correct position so it starts in point 1 and ends in point 2.

So let's say I have

point 1 `SCNVector3(x: 0.0538790673, y: 39.1349449, z: 31.1199818)`

point 2 `SCNVector3(x: 36.4344292, y: 32.6111221, z: 10.442565)`.

One represents New York on the sphere, the other one is London. I have an arc with angle `54.303051` represents the line. I am unable rotate it so the arc starts in New York and finishes in London.

All of the nodes mentioned above are at origin [0, 0, 0].

I am stuck on this problem, any suggestion or idea is very welcome

Thank you

[image: What is looks like]

Comment: You said: "I already have code that takes in latitude/longitude and maps it to X,Y,Z coordinate."  -- how do you know that you did this correctly?

Comment: Search *spherical interpolation* ("Slerp")

Comment: Lou Franco, I drew something at calculated X,Y,Z and it was in the area I expected. So one latitude/longitude was in New York City and the other one was in London. My calculation of X,Y,Z doesn't take curvature of Earth into account but that shouldn't matter on this scale.

Comment: Are you able achieve this? I am also facing same problem.